# OFX File parser in C#

Tags: c#, ofx

I am looking for an OFX file parser library in C#. I have search the web but there seems to be none. Does anyone know of any good quality C# OFX file parser. I need to process some bank statements files which are in OFX format.

**Update**
I have managed to find a C# library for parsing OFX parser.

Here is the link [ofx sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ofx-sharp/). This codebase seems to be the best case to startup my solution.

Comment: @JLWarlow - I did check that post before asking that question. Here I am only interested in C# and .NET parser library. Not Gnu or some other libraries. Please read my question again.

Comment: There's a detail in ofx sharp: It not parse time in datetime, only date

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the ofx sharp library, but realised it doesn't work is the file is not valid XML ... it seems to parse but has empty values ...

I made a change in the OFXDocumentParser.cs where I first fix the file to become valid XML and then let the parser continue. Not sure if you experienced the same issue?

Inside of the method:

```
private string SGMLToXML(string file)
```

I added a few lines first to take file to newfile and then let the SqmlReader process that after the following code:

```
string newfile = ParseHeader(file);

newfile = SGMLToXMLFixer.Fix_SONRS(newfile);
newfile = SGMLToXMLFixer.Fix_STMTTRNRS(newfile);
newfile = SGMLToXMLFixer.Fix_CCSTMTTRNRS(newfile);


//reader.InputStream = new StringReader(ParseHeader(file));
reader.InputStream = new StringReader(newfile);
```

SGMLToXMLFixer is new class I added into the OFXSharp library. It basically scans all the tags that open and verifies it has a closing tag too.

```
namespace OFXSharp
{
    public static class SGMLToXMLFixer
    {
        public static string Fix_SONRS(string original) 
        { .... }

        public static string Fix_STMTTRNRS(string original) 
        { .... }

        public static string Fix_CCSTMTTRNRS(string original) 
        { .... }

        private static string Fix_Transactions(string file, string transactionTag, int lastIdx, out int lastIdx_new) 
        { .... }

        private static string Fix_Transactions_Recursive(string file_modified, int lastIdx, out int lastIdx_new) 
        { .... }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Ofx_to_DataSet.aspx. The code uses Framework 3.5 and transforms an ofx into a dataset, this may help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Accepted, since this might provide some startup options though I will be doing this in EF Code First.